# Errors with redefinitions after upgrade to XCode 3.2.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, redefinition

I recently upgraded to Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2.5 so I could test on my iPod Touch and iPhone and ran into some problems with the project I was working on. First it couldn't find a Base SDK, then my old frameworks weren't hooking up correctly. Finally after setting the Project Format to Xcode 3.1 compatible (3.2 also worked) and the Base SDK for all configurations to iOS 4.2, then setting my iOS deployment target to iOS 3.0 I was able to get the system to find a Base SDK and attempt a build. That's when the frameworks didn't want to cooperate. 4/6 I'm using displayed in red, so I re routed the path to the iPhone simulator 4.2 platform which worked perfectly. I was able to build my project, no errors or warnings and my app worked fine. I went to work last night thinking I had fixed the problem. This morning I fired up the laptop and went to build my code base and now have 1142 errors all of which have to do with code I haven't written deemed as being redefined. Suggestions? The following is just a small sample of the error list (obviously don't need to see all 1142)

//Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:48: error: redefinition of 'NSMakeCollectable'

/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:65: error: duplicate interface declaration for class 'NSObject'

/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:67: error: redefinition of 'struct NSObject'

Comment: Did you accidentally use `#include` instead of `#import` in one of your files? `#import` prevents you from recursive inclusion.

Comment: No, just went back and double checked, #import on all of them. This is the same exact code/project that ran fine last night, in fact I can still launch it from the simulator. Just today when I try to build it, I have 1142 errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up deleting all frameworks from the project and re adding them as existing frameworks, then cleaning all targets and it worked.